# Download JSON file in laravel 5.6

Tags: json, laravel, download

I'm trying to download a JSON file using this code but my JSON file downloaded with `.txt` extension.
All the other extension's file works fine with there content-Type. but not with JSON extension.

This is my code :

```
$file= public_path(). "/download/".$file_id."/manifest.json";
 $headers = array(
   'Content-Type: application/json'
 );
 return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::download($file,'manifest.json',$headers);
```

Comment: the code is ok. do you use any library from the front-end to download the file?

Comment: no, I just call this code via url

Answer (score 0):

I installed new Laravel 5.6 project, and I use

```
Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
    $file= storage_path(). "/app/countries.json";
    $headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::download($file,'manifest.json',$headers);
});
```

and I download the file correctly

[image]

[image]

I dont know if maybe can try using storage folder

Answer (score 0):

I think it is something with my chrome browser. I try to download my file using Firefox and it works fine.